# glib g_array_append_val() acting strange

Tags: c, glib

I have this very simple piece of code. I declare a glib array of doubles in C. Then I fill it using the g_array_append_val() function and, lastly, I print out the array content. The printed out version doesn't show the array items to be 0.0, 1.0, 2.0,..9.0 as I would expect. What could be wrong with this? Any ideas?

```
GArray *data;
data = g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, sizeof(double));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    double d =  (double)i;
    g_array_append_val(data, d);
}
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%f ", g_array_index(data, double, i));

free(data);
```

The output is here:

```
0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

I even looked up the test suite for the glib library and saw them doing it this exact way. This baffles me.

Comment: That works for me as part of a minimal test case (I basically just stuffed that in a main() with a couple of includes).  Does it work for you when you do that?  I'm thinking there may be some memory corruption elsewhere in your program which is causing problems here…

Comment: You're right. It must be some sort of a memory corruption. I ran this inside a test suite function. There was nothing else in the function, though. As soon as I moved it to the main function and removed everything else from it (no calls of test functions), it started working. It looks like my test suite somehow corrupts the memory. Thanks for your help and sorry for posting a question that will probably not be very useful to others. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user nemequ sent me in the right direction. I found out that in another function call, I was releasing the data GArray using the free(data); call, which is not good. GArrays are supposed to be released using g_array_free(data, TRUE); That was my problem. The memory got corrupted.